# How to create configuration for liberty for redirecting to another URL

Tags: websphere-8

I need to create some configuration on the liberty server for redirecting one URL to another one and set the specific cookie, headers e.g. It will be some proxy layer. But I have never worked with the liberty and I can not find the info on how I can do that.

It looks like:

1. Send a request to liberty(URL https:URL_A.com)
2. The liberty redirect to URL_B.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberty is not a proxy server. You need IHS (IBM HTTP Server) or Apache in front of it to do this redirect. You can also use WebSphere Plugin with IHS or Apache to configure it to pass requests to Liberty.

Of course, you can write your own Java app to do that redirect and put it in Liberty, but I think setting up IHS/Apache is better for that case.

Comment: maybe do you some good tutorials how to set up it ?

Comment: Here is link how to configure IHS with Liberty https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTJ_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_install_config_liberty.html and check this for various Apache rewrite examples https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html